# supress unused area in RainCloudplot - Python

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using PtitPrince and Seaborn to plot RainClouds on Python, and I have "gaps" in my data (a time timeseries, where event can not happen), which I would like to suppress.

**My figure looks like this:**

[image: figure]

**But I would like to have it without the blue blocks**, as no event can happen during these times:

[image]

**My script:**

```
dx = "ThreatType"; dy = "InTrialHitTime"; dhue = "Collection_Group"; ort = "h"; pal = "husl"; sigma = .1
ax=pt.RainCloud(x = dx, y = dy, data = df, palette = pal, bw = sigma,
                 width_viol = .7, figsize = (12,7), orient = ort, alpha= .40, dodge = True, pointplot = True)
ax.set_yticklabels(['High Shock', 'Low Shock'])
ax.set_xlabel('Devil hit time')
```

Comment: You are plotting some data on a linear axis. On such axis, the distance between successive multiples is always the same. Maybe you want to plot part of your data on four individual axes instead?